# Yarn works in Git bash, but not in Powershell

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, hadoop-yarn, windows-11

I installed Node 18.16.0 ( using nvm ) onWindows 11 and activated Yarn.
I can use yarn from git bash,
but when I tried to use it in other terminals (power shell), got this error:

yarn cannot be loaded